# file sharing service with iOS API

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-s3, dropbox

I'm looking for a file sharing service to host all my app's files.
The idea is to update the file sharing account, and let the app download from there every time it loads.

I tried dropbox, but they request the user to enter their login details every time, and that's not what i'm looking for.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Dropbox has an SDK, no. Can't you save the login/password after you get it once from the user, then supply it on each launch? You can save this info in the keychain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Amazon Web Services S3 is a pretty good for file sharing.  The link is [here](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).